# MediaElement Source Property Not Working with Video in VideosLibrary

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a mp4 video in the KnownFolders.VideoLibrary folder, and I can play it through the MediaElement Control (MyPlayer) as a stream with this code:

```
var file = await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFileAsync("video.mp4");
var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
MyPlayer.SetSource(stream, file.FileType);
```

But I cannot make it play using the Source property:

```
var file = await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFileAsync("video.mp4");
MyPlayer.Source = new Uri(file.Path, UriKind.Absolute);
```

But the Source property works for a local assets file:

```
MyPlayer.Source = new Uri(this.BaseUri, "Assets/video.mp4");
```

Any ideas why? I'm also having problems binding the video to the Source property in XAML whenever the file sits in the VideoLibrary folder. Works great if the file is an asset to the app.

Now if I *must* use a stream and SetSource for videos in the library, how do I bind it from a ViewModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this problem by using a ContentControl and bind a MediaElement to it instead. I wrote a short blog post about it.

[Binding MediaElement to a ViewModel in a Windows 8 Store App](http://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/archive/2012/12/14/binding-mediaelement-to-a-viewmodel-in-a-windows-8-store-app.aspx)